# Laravel 5: Call to Undefined Method Response::header() when trying to access data through API?

Tags: api, laravel-5, cors, access-control

I built an API with Laravel with a CORS middleware.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, Authorization, X-XSRF-TOKEN');
    }
}
```

When trying to access data via API, `localhost:8000/api/items`, I get the following URL on my Laravel terminal and

> Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::header()

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know it's kind of late, but I had similar issue when using the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse`.

As you said the problem was the

> Call to undefined method ... ::header()

So clearly the `header` method is not present on an object.

For me the solution was to use `headers` method, which returns you the `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag`.

Use it like so:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-XSRF-TOKEN');
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: U SAVED MY LIFE : GogromaT YOU ARE JUST awesome !

Answer (score 0):

try by this way , this should fix your CORS issues, declaring it into your class's constructor. and it will let you API work.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{

   public function __construct(Request $request) {

        $request->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $request->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    }
}
```

why people is voting negative to this answer ? this work aswell and fine than others , im currently using in a production site , i was the first solution answer for the guy that request for that help intime.